# Conditional Delete Button in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a delete button in my gridview, but I want this button not to work depending on the result of an sql query.

An example

I have a gridview with "ship containers", and I want to remove one of the container from this list, but I want to display a message "to be able to delete this container, please remove it from the products", so that if a ship container is in use, I need to prevent it from being deleted.

Comment: It's not helpful to know that you're going to delete ship-containers, but it would be helpful to see what you've tried.

Comment: actually I did not try because I don't have any idea. that comes to my mind, I am able to catch the button click by on rowcommand, but what kind of if condition to write inside that rowcommand? what piece of code would cancel that delete command.

Comment: You just need to execute a query first to check if the container is still in use, then you can either show the message or execute the delete command.

Comment: Yes that is the structure, but which piece of code executes the delete command? or prevent execution of delete command. The point that I am stuck is this if statement.

Comment: The delete command can be a simple ado.net-command which gets executed only if  the query to check if its in use returns false. You dont know how to write the correct the sql-statement? What rdbms are you using, what is the datasource of the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way you can do this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EntityGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DocumentId" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="False" SkinID="GridViewSmall" OnRowCommand="EntityGridView_RowCommand"
    OnPageIndexChanged="EntityGridView_PageIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="TemplateFieldThreeColumns">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageAlign="Top" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% #ResolveImageUrl(Eval("Extension").ToString()) %>'
                    ToolTip='<%# Eval("Extension").ToString() %>' CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocumentId") %>' />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="<% $resources:AppResource,Delete %>"
                SkinID="DeletePage" OnClientClick="<%# GetDeleteConfirmation(Resources.AppResource.ConfirmDocumentDelete) %>"
                CommandName="CustomDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocumentId") %>' Visible='<% #AllowDocDelete(Container.DataItem) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,Title %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,Author %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,FileName %>" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="<% $resources:AppResource,Created %>" />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="EmptyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.NoContentToDisplay %>' CssClass="NoDataLabel"></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Take notice on AllowDocDelete function that disables delete button. This function should be declared inslide your page class, something like this:

```
    public bool AllowDocDelete(object item)
    {
        bool result = false; 
        //TODO: check your condition
        return result;
    }
```

Item object represents binded entity.

Comment: I am quite close to my solution, your codes is AllowDocDelete(Container.DataItem), I did not understand this part, I need to send my containerId as a string parameter to AllowDocDelete function, normally I get it by <%# Bind("ContainerId") %>, but how to do that inside the function?

Comment: Call AllowDocDelete(Eval("ContainerId")) and ContainerId value will be passed to the function.